TortoiseSVN: Undo Commit with "Replaced" Files
In a recent SVN commit log several files are now marked as "Replacing" - the files have been deleted and re-added by the commit. This sounds odd, but I understand that this can happen after doing an SVN update which has (these) files with merge conflicts and then doing 'resolve using "mine"' on them.
I think that this was a mistake and the problem is that the revision history has been "lost" (actually, it's there but is no longer reported against the affected files).
My question is, can I revert this commit such that the revision history is recovered?
I haven't tried doing this yet as I don't want to risk making matters worse.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I've managed to sort this out.
Fortunately this occurred on a branch so I was able to create a new branch from the affected one at the point just before the mistake occurred. I could then inform people to switch to this one.
(The affected branch I've renamed with '_DoNotUse' suffix too.)
Doing this means that the file history of the affected files is no longer broken simply because this wasn't the case at the point that this new branch was made.
